# create ActiveXComponent using JACOB is slow under citrix

Tags: java, citrix, jacob

I've created an application which uses JACOB to generate Word-Files.
Which works perfect for me.

But now we had to migrate the workstations to citrix.
Now the application is very slow. I've found out that the most time is lost generating the Word file(especially creating the ActiveXComponent)

On my developer PC creating the ActiveXComponent with 
    new ActiveXComponent(APP_ID_WORD);
takes about 300ms.
Under citrix it needs 3 seconds (just to create the ActiveXComponent)
and additionally 600-700ms to open the document.

If i open a word file by doubleclicking it takes about 1.5-2 seconds till its completely open!

any suggestions how to make this faster? (Or is it really completely limited by the citrix environment.)